# Stuck on git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

My ultimate goal is to get CoreStore installed from github.

The instructions for CoreStore say to use the following to install as a git submodule: `git submodule add https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore.git <destination directory>`. From what I understood from the git submodule [discussion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), I need to enter this command from my $GIT_DIR, which I understand to mean the directory where my superproject's .git folder resides.

But I can't seem to make it work. A tutorial I read suggests creating subfolders under $GIT_DIR and putting the submodule there. But if I enter the name of an existing directory called "foo" for `<destination directory>`, I get `'foo' already exists and is not a valid git repo`. If I enter the name of a non-existent directory, I get `A git directory for 'foo' is found locally with remote(s): fatal: Not a git repository: '.git/modules/foo'`.

If I leave the folder name off, I get a CoreStore folder in my superproject's $GIT_DIR, which seems almost sensible, and I see that CoreStore and .gitmodules have been staged. Also seemingly sensible . But when I try to commit them, I get `fatal: Path '.gitmodules' exists on disk, but not in 'HEAD'.`

I have overcommit, which hooks into git to validate commits. I turned on overcommit's debug mode, and twice during the commit attempt it says `STDERR: "warning: unable to rmdir 'CoreStore': Directory not empty\n"`. I also disabled overcommit, and the fatal error message went away, but I can't tell whether that's because the problem is fixed, or because everything is broken beyond repair.

I've read the [theory](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) of submodules, and I think I understand them, I just can't figure out how to work with them. I've looked at [some](https://blog.axosoft.com/learn-git-submodule/) [articles](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407), and a [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/155150/dependency-management-using-git-submodules), but the articles don't address syntax in a helpful way, and the tutorial describes a behavior from git that is nothing like what I'm seeing. Even the git [instructions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_workflow_for_a_third_party_library) that seem to apply directly to my situation don't work for me. I'm in over my head.

git version 2.16.2

overcommit 0.43.0

**Edit: To reproduce:**

1. mkdir foo; cd foo; git init
2. Create dummy text file in foo; commit
3. git submodule command goes here
4. git status reports that .gitmodules and CoreStore are ready to be committed
5. git commit
6. Observe some overcommit output, an ugly git error, then more overcommit output

Comment: I can replicate the intended flow in a dummy repo with `git init repo && cd repo && git submodule add https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore.git && git status && git commit -m "test"` and everything works just fine. Does that work for you? If not, some combination of `git` and `overcommit` is not working on your system, else its something specific to your repo.

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me too. Sorry I didn't say that in my original post. To reproduce, after the init, I added one file and committed it. Then I did the submodule stuff. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: But you've helped me already -- I see from your example that I'm not totally abusing the submodule command, and probably haven't broken anything. Thanks again.